# C# .NET Images not showing up in Local Resource

Tags: c#, .net

I'm creating an app in C# .NET Core.

I have a button that I want to apply a image background to, but whenever I try to find the image in my local resource it doesn't show up.

[image]

I know it's not a file size problem, because I made a copy of "smalldownarrow" and the copy doesn't show up either.

- I've tried rebuilding my project
- manually setting the code to the image like so

```
    this.button1Merge.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("GradientButton1.Image")));
```

- using a Picturebox controller, doesn't show up either.

Comment: Is there another folder called `DevContent`? Search using Command Prompt - `dir *.png /s`.

Comment: Right click -> Properties on one of the files in Visual Studio and it will show the full path to the file (including the actual folder it is in).

Comment: @mjwills Thank You! For some strange reason everytime I click the "Import..." button it directed to "\repos\PDFTool\PDFTool\DevContent"(an old copy of the project) instead of "repos\xPDF\PDFTool\DevContent"(new copy of the project). I have no idea why its directing to a different project.